# How to print out a element and all the elements ina list

Tags: java, bluej

When I try to run(use) the last method, it start running and never stops. Also When I try to print out aJob the element does not print out correctly. It comes out with odd letters. I am posting the whole class because I am guessing that I am making a mistake somewhere else apart from runJod and runAll methods. could anyone tell me what I need to do to fix this please?

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 */

public class JobQueue

{
    private ArrayListmyJobInQueue; //a list of job to be done

```
private ArrayList<Job>myFinishedJobs;// a list of compleated job

private int myJobDuration; //duration if one job

private int myTimeLeft;//total time left 
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class JobQueue
 */
 public JobQueue()
{
  myJobInQueue = new ArrayList<Job>();
  myFinishedJobs = new ArrayList<Job>();
  myJobDuration =0; 
  myTimeLeft=0;  
}

/**
 * Return the list of jobs that have not been completed (including the current job).
 */
 public ArrayList<Job> getPendingJobs()
 {
  return myJobInQueue;  
 }

/**
 * Return the list of jobs that have been completed.
 */
 public ArrayList<Job> getCometedJobs()
 {
  return myFinishedJobs;
 } 

/**
 * Return the job at the front of the pending queue, or null if the queue is empty.
 */
 public Job getCurrentJob()
 {
   if(myJobInQueue!=null)
   { 
    Job FirstJobInTheQueue = myJobInQueue.get(0);   
    return FirstJobInTheQueue;
   }
   else
   {
    return null;
   }

 } 

/**
 * Return the amount of time left on the clock (as an integer)
 */
 public int getTimeLeft()//Ok
 {
   return myTimeLeft; 
 }

/**
 * Return the total duration of all the pending jobs(as an integer).
 */

 public int getTotalDuration()
 {
   int myTimeLeft= 0;
   for(int i = 0; i<myJobInQueue.size();i++)
   {
       int num = myJobInQueue.getDuration(i); //I think this line is wrong. 
       myTimeLeft = myTimeLeft + num ;
   }
   return myTimeLeft;
 }

/**
 * Add a Job to the end of the Queue
 */ 
 public void addJob(Job job)
 {   
    if(job!=null)
    {
      myJobInQueue.add(job);
    }
 }

/**
  * Add the specified number of seconds to the clock.
  */
 public void addTime(int seconds)
 {
    if(seconds>0)
    {
      myTimeLeft = myTimeLeft  + seconds;
    }
 }

 /**
  * Run the first job on the queue if there is enough time on the clock and the job queue list is not empty.
  * And move the job to the finished jobs list.
  */

 public void runAJob(){
   if(!myJobInQueue.isEmpty())
   {
        myJobDuration = myJobInQueue.get(0).getDuration();
        if (myJobDuration < myTimeLeft)
        {
            myTimeLeft = myTimeLeft - myJobDuration;
            myFinishedJobs.add(myJobInQueue.get(0));
            System.out.println("A job is running: " + myJobInQueue.get(0).getName());
            myJobInQueue.remove(0);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Not enogth running time left, please add time on the clock.");             
        }
   }
   else 
   {
     System.out.println("No pending job on the list.");
   }
}

/**
  * Run all the jobs on the queue in order until it runs out of time.
 */   


public void runAll()
{
  for(int i = 0; myTimeLeft > 0 && myTimeLeft > myJobDuration;i++);
  {
    runJob();

  }
   System.out.println("Job can not be run, not enough time left." );   
}

}
```

Comment: Is the line `System.out.println("Ajob is running"+ myJobInQueue.get(0));` not printing at all, or is it printing something unexpected?

Comment: I is printing out as A job is runningAssignment3.Job@ab1ff2 for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment, the line `System.out.println("Ajob is running"+ myJobInQueue.get(0));` is printing out the object reference for the `Job` returned by `myJobInQueue.get(0)`.  In order for that line to print out meaningful information, just make sure `Job` has a `toString` method that returns a `String` that describes the object.

I think your second problem is caused by the `myTimeLeft` variable dropping below `myJobDuration`, but not below 0.  I don't see where you decrement `myTimeLeft` when it's in this window.

Side Note: Do all jobs have the same duration?  If not, then you should probably be using the duration for the next `Job` instead of a global `myJobDuration` variable.

Answer (score 3):

Point 1: `myJobInQueue.get(0)`
is not printing correct values.

this will print correct values if your `Job` has `toString()` method as Bill mentioned on his answer.
another approach is to call the getter method of your Job class if any such as

```
myJobInQueue.get(0).getJobName();
```

Point2: debug it and see the value of `myTimeLeft` is it really get below zero at any point.

Comment: With the help of everyone responded me I have altered `runAJob`method as above,and it seems to be working ok.

But maybe I don't I under stand `toString` method clearly.... I am trying to learn to call method from 1 class to another class.

what would I have to do...

If `Job` class have a method to `run` the individual job itself and I want to call the `run` method in the `Job` class into `runAjob` method. So when `run` method in a Job class gets executed it connects to `runAjob` method so it gets executed as well.

Comment: Object's toString method returns a String representation of the object. see here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not too clear for me, but this scenario seems to be appropriate to use the **Java concurrency** package, especially the **Executor** related parts [Java concurrency: Executor Interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)  .

I would use an executor with a single thread worker (it occurs to me that you want your jobs to be completed one by one, otherwise use more threads), and a CountDownLatch with the number of jobs to complete. And after submitting the job Runnables (which decrement the latch once finished) to the ExecutorService, I'd issue a latch.await(timeout).

**EDIT** on a second thought, you don't need the magic with the latch, something along these lines would be enough I think:

```
public void runMyJobs(List<Runnable> myJobs, long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException {

  ExecutorService e = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
  for(Runnable job: myJobs) {
    e.execute(job);    
  }

  e.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
  List<Runnable> notCompletedJobs = e.shutdownNow();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of everyone responded me I have altered runAJob method as above,and it seems to be working ok.

But maybe I don't I under stand toString method clearly.... 
I am trying to learn to call method from 1 class to another class??

what would I have to do...

If Job class have a method to run the individual job itself and I want to call the "run" method in the "Job" class into "runAjob" method. So when "run" method in a Job class gets executed it connects to "runAjob" method so it gets executed as well.

I mean if we have 2 pending jobs in myJobInQueue.

0-{"Do Washing" 10min}

1-{"Cook dinner" 10min}

2-{"Wash car" 10min}

and when I use "run" method myJobInQueue becomes,

0-{"Cook dinner" 10min}

1-{"Wash car" 10min}

and

when I use "runAjob" method myJobInQueue becomes,

0-{"Wash car" 10min}

I hope I have made this question clear enough.